# Use custom authorization logic with AWS Cognito authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cognito

We have a Cognito User Pool which contains the users we would like to allow access to, to our API. Our API uses Lambda functions to service the endpoints. The Cognito pool is configured with a custom field `roles` which is essentially a comma-separated list of roles that user possesses.

Now, first, we want the Cognito authentication to take place (to determine whether the user does belong to our pool and the credentials are valid). Then, we somehow want to run our custom logic to run which will look at the `roles` field which it will receive through the claims, and then allow or deny the request based on internal business logic.

We tried using a custom authorizer to implement this logic and set it as the authorizer for our endpoints. Then, we enabled Cognito authorization for this authorizer function. The problem is that since Cognito protects API endpoints and not lambda functions per se, the Cognito authorization simply does not run when an API endpoint is hit and the custom authorizer is called.

How do we achieve our objective of using custom logic with Cognito authorization? Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "The problem is that since Cognito protects API endpoints and not lambda functions per se, the Cognito authorization simply does not run when an API endpoint is hit and the custom authorizer is called."

Comment: The lambda authorizer is protected with the Cognito authorization via API gateway. (HTTP event). But we are executing it via custom authorizer setting (REQUEST event type). Hence Cognito authorization is not invoked at all, before running the custom authorizer.

Answer (score 1):

All of the claims in the users' token are available in the context that can be passed to your lambda function if you are using cognito authorizers under `$context.authorizer.claims.property` Would mapping that claim into your lambda function and checking that the roles is present at the beginning of your lambda work for you?